# Multidimensional Guassian intergral over only some variables

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Doing a multidimensional (or even infinite-dimensional) Gaussian integral of the form

\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{j}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{j}\right]\mathrm{Exp}\left(-\textbf{X}^{T}\cdot\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{X}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

is a standard technique. Where $\textbf{X}$ is a vector of the $x_{j}$'s and $\textbf{A}$ is the coupling matrix (real, symmetric, and with positive determinant).

This is solved by making the transformation

\begin{eqnarray}
\textbf{X}^{T}\textbf{A}\textbf{X}\rightarrow \textbf{X}^{T}\textbf{O}^{T}\cdot\textbf{O}\textbf{A}\textbf{O}^{T}\cdot\textbf{O}\textbf{X}=\textbf{Y}^{T}\textbf{D}\textbf{Y}
\end{eqnarray}

where $\textbf{O}$ is the orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{O}\textbf{X}=\textbf{Y}$ is a linear change of variables with a Jacobian of one. Since $\textbf{D}$ is diagonal all the integrals decouple and can be solved individually.

My question is what do I do if I only want to integrate over *some* of the variables? Is there a way to decompose the coupling matrix such that it can be diagonalized only over some of its entries?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$
\mathbf A=\pmatrix{
\mathbf B&\mathbf C\\
\mathbf C^\top&\mathbf D
}
$$

and

$$
\mathbf X=\pmatrix{\mathbf U\\\mathbf V}\;,
$$

where $\mathbf U$ contains the variables you want to integrate over. Then

\begin{align}
\mathbf X^\top\mathbf A\mathbf X
&=\mathbf U^\top\mathbf B\mathbf U+2\mathbf V^\top\mathbf C^\top\mathbf U+\mathbf V^\top\mathbf D\mathbf V\\
&=\left(\mathbf U+\mathbf B^{-1}\mathbf C\mathbf V\right)^\top \mathbf B\left(\mathbf U+\mathbf B^{-1}\mathbf C\mathbf V\right)+\mathbf V^\top\left(\mathbf D-\mathbf C^\top\mathbf B^{-1}\mathbf C\right)\mathbf V\;.
\end{align}

The first term can be shifted to yield an integral over $\exp\left(-\mathbf U^\top\mathbf B\mathbf U\right)$, and the second term remains as a lower-dimensional Gaussian.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but I admit that I am still a bit confused. What do you mean that the first term can be "shifted"? If I do a change of variables, say $\textbf{U}+\textbf{B}^{-1}\textbf{CV}\rightarrow \textbf{U}'$ then $\textbf{U}$ and $\textbf{V}$ are no longer independent variables and I can't do the integral.

Comment: @quantum_loser: What do you mean by "no longer independent variables"? The shift is exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now after just staring for a while. If I write the change of variables between $(\textbf{U}', \, \textbf{V}')$ and $(\textbf{U}, \, \textbf{V})$, with of-course $\textbf{V}'=\textbf{V}$ then the determenent of the jacobian is one and everything goes through. I honestly am not sure why I didn't understand this earlier...